# Struggling with passing messages through MVVM Light

Tags: windows-8, mvvm-light

I have two view and their corresponding ViewModels and i want to send text from one view to another using MVVM Light as follows

in first viewmodel i am calling the following method

```
public void NavigatePage()
    {
        string temp = "temp value";

        Messenger.Default.Send("temp");

        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (frame != null) frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage), temp);
    }
```

while in page 2 view model i am having the following code

```
public MyViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, MessageReceived);
    }
    private string test;

    public string Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set { test = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Test");}
    }

    private void MessageReceived(string message)
    {
        Test = message;
    }
```

when i debug my code the ctor of this viewmodel is getting called but the MessageReceived is not getting called hence property Test is never getting set, I am missing something, please help

Comment: Try specifying the type of message being sent Messenger.Default.Send<string>("temp");

Comment: sorry but it dosn't help

Comment: Are you sure, you have MyViewModel created **before** NavigatePage()
is executed? The way mvvm light messages work you should subscribe before sending in order to receive something (as the message handling occurs immediatelym when you execute Send method)

Answer (score 0):

Is the `SecondViewModel` actually created before you send the message? You can specify this in the `ViewModelLocator` class.

In the locator you have to register your viewmodel and CREATE it when the applications starts.
Like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SecondViewModel>(true);
```

With the `true` parameter the `SecondViewModel` will be created when the application is started! :)